# which python library to serialize a poorly designed class

Tags: python, serialization, pickle, dill

Can anybody help me to understand how and why to choose among e.g. `pickle` and `dill`?

My use case is the following.
I would like to dump an object which instance of a class derived by multiple inheritance from some external library classes. Moreover one attribute of the class is a dictionary, which has a function as a value.
Unfortunately, that function is defined within the scope of the class.

```
def class:
    def f():
      def that_function():
        # do someth
      # back within f() scope
      self.mydata{'foo':that_function}
```

Any comment regard to robustness to external dependencies?

Or any other library I could consider for serialization?

Comment: I love this question title

Comment: I hope it is better now

Comment: probably more helpful as a question but less funny :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the `dill` author.  You should use `pickle` if all the objects you want to pickle can be pickled by `pickle.dump`.  If one or more of the objects are unpicklable with `pickle`, then use `dill`.  See the `pickle` docs for what can be pickled with `pickle`.  `dill` can pickle most python objects, with some exceptions.

If you want to consider alternatives to `dill`, there's `cloudpickle`, which has a similar functionality to `dill` (and is very similar to `dill` when using `dill.settings['recurse'] = True`).

There are other serialization libraries, like `json`, but they actually serialize less objects than pickle does, so you'd not choose them to serialize a user-built class.